# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near on insert

Tags: c#, .net

How can i fix the problem ?

```cs
public DataAccessResponse InsertPlayer(Players NewPlayer)
{
    try
    {
        DataBaseCommand com = new DataBaseCommand();
        com.SetCommand("insert into players (firstname,lastname,birthdate,position,age,weight,height,teamid) values ('" +
            NewPlayer.FirstName + "', '" + NewPlayer.LastName + "', '" + NewPlayer.BirthDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'),'" +
            NewPlayer.Position + "', '" + NewPlayer.Age + "', '" + NewPlayer.Weight + "', '" + NewPlayer.Height + "', '" +
            NewPlayer.TeamID + "')");
        com.OpenConnection();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        com.CloseConnection();

        return new DataAccessResponse(true, null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new DataAccessResponse(false, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use parameters in your SQL, like you always should - http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: Even easier, if you use dapper, and name your parameters the same as the properties in your Players class, it'll do all the wiring for you and your insert becomes literally a single line of code. Avoid using use plural class names - if Players is a collection of players, call it PlayerCollection (but here it looks to be a single player)

Comment: it's all okey now, thanks

Comment: OT why do you have an Age column, when you also have a Birthdate? And why does it appear to be a varchar value (as do Weight and Height)?

Comment: You have another issue: you are not disposing your connection properly, you should use `using` blocks

Comment: You're right for age, i will fix this but with connection i don't see any problem. :)

Comment: Kinda puzzled why your error message says "on insert" when your code does not contain this phrase. Is it certainly this code that throws the error?

Comment: This is my mistake the text was "at line 1" because of one scope. This is my first post here but am learning.

Answer (score 0):

1. install Dapper
2. Write a code like:

```
    using(var c = new MySqlConnection("your connection string here")
      c.Execute(
        @"insert into players (firstname,lastname,birthdate,position,age,weight,height,teamid) 
          values (@FirstName,@LastName,@BirthDate,@Position,@Age,@Weight,@Height,@TeamID)", 
        NewPlayer
    );
```

Or if you additionally install Dapper Contrib, then the insert gets easier:

```
c.Insert(NewPlayer);
```

If your column/table names and property/class names differ you can use attributes to map them. See here https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/08/05/dapper-in-net-core-part-4-dapper-contrib/

Comment: Thanks for suggestions and for help. :)